# What is the difference between HBASE and HDFS in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

What is the actual difference, and when should be use the other when data needs to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/hadoop-vs-cassandra-and-hbase.html) for a good explanation. But in general, HBASE runs on top of HDFS. HDFS is a distributed file system just like any other file system (Unix/Windows) and HBASE is like a database which reads and writes from that file system just like any other database (MySQL, MSSQL).